# Intercepting databases accesses with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm looking for a way to intercept database queries as a means of getting some more in-depth performance stats. I'm after number of queries, query duration, the result data (for an idea of data magnitude) and ideally some access to any LINQ expression.

I can fall back on extending a base context class, creating another method to get `DbSet`, returning a wrapper there, but 1) that seems hackier than it ought to be, 2) any code there won't be able to distinguish getting cached results vs actual database accesses..

I've looked through the code and feel like wrapping `ExecutionStrategyFactory` or `Database` is the way to go - and while I can create an extension method on `RelationalDbContextOptionsBuilder` for the former, or /replace/ services, I can't see a way of wrapping either, such that the underlying provider's implementation is still used.

(See also: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6967)

Is there a decent place to hook into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ref of anyone else:

Ok, the trick is:

1. Replace the `IRelationalConnection` that EF Core's DI system uses via `ReplaceService<IRelationalConnection, MyRc>()`. Our new `MyRc` will wrap the existing connection to add hooks
2. In our `MyRc`, have a constructor param of `IDatabaseProviderServices`. The EF DI system will populate it. Cast that to `IRelationalDatabaseProviderServices` and then grab the `RelationalConnection` property from that
3. Wrap all methods, but have public `DbConnection DbConnection { get; }` return an instance of a `DbConnection`-wrapping class
4. In *that* wrapping class, have `CreateDbCommand()` return an instance of a `DbCommand`-wrapping class
5. In *that* wrapping class, have `ExecuteDbDataReader()` return an instance of a `DbDataReader`-wrapping class

Then, in the `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` wrappers, we can see what commands and parameters are being sent to the database, and the results coming back.

This only works with relational models.

Comment: And how do you do that for EFCore 2.0? I have an issue with the IDatabaseProviderServices. My Visual Studio cannot find it, and I even believe it's not in there anymore.

Comment: Looks to have been binned

Comment: binned? how so?